# Difference between S = abs(S).^2 and S = S.^2

Tags: matlab

I've been told that the `abs(S)` function changes all negative values in an array into positive, absolute values. In this case, `S` is a huge array of tens of thousands of values between -1 and 1.

So, as I understand it, taking the values inside the array to second power should have the exact same end result.

```
abs([4 -4 2]).^2 -> [4 4 2].^2 = [16 16 4]
[4 -4 2].^2 = [16 16 4]
```

If that's the case, why does changing `S = abs(S).^2` to `S = S.^2` create the following error a few lines of code later?

```
Error using image
Invalid datatype for Image CData. Numeric or logical matrix required for image CData.

Error in imagesc (line 39)
hh = image(varargin{:},'CDataMapping','scaled');

Error in IHAVENOIDEAWHATIMDOING (line 53)
subplot(411); imagesc(T,F,10*log10(S),ratio);
```

Comment: what is `class(S)` ?

Comment: What is the actual `S` that results in the error? `S = abs(S).^2` and `S = S.^2` will only be different if `S` has non-zero imaginary components.

Comment: S is a huge array of values between -1 and 1. Adding to question

Answer (score 3):

Judging by your examples, it seems like your `S` matrix contains **negative values**, then, when applying `log10` to them, you get complex numbers and `imagesc` complains.

Ex:

```
>> imagesc(log10(-4))

Error using image
Invalid datatype for Image CData. Numeric or logical matrix required for image CData.

Error in imagesc (line 18)
    hh = image(varargin{1},'CDataMapping','scaled');
```

You should make sure that you are supplying valid datatypes to `imagesc` - they are listed at the bottom of [this documentation section](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html#inputarg_C):

> **Data Types**: `single` | `double` | `int8` | `int16` | `int32` | `int64` | `uint8` | `uint16` | `uint32` | `uint64` | `logical`

(As you can see, `complex double` etc. are not accepted).

Of course, it could also be something else, we can't really know without a full example.

Comment: I neglected to mention this, but the line where imagesc is used, is several lines below S = S.^2. Your answer doesn't answer my question, which is "what is the difference between S=abs(S).^2 and S=S.^2. Your answer assumes that I used unaltered S in imagesc - I didn't.

Comment: The error in your code has nothing to do with your question either. All I assumed was that you were supplying invalid inputs to `imagesc`, and gave an example using negative numbers. If your `S` had complex values, `log10(S.^2)` would result in these invalid values. I second [horchler's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453194/difference-between-s-abss-2-and-s-s-2/46454646?noredirect=1#comment79862843_46453194). Unfortunately, assumptions were necessary since the question is incomplete. Please see [mcve].

Comment: Well, something is going on there. If I use `S = abs(S).^2` the script runs just fine, but when I change it to `S = S.^2`, I get the error I quoted. I have no idea why, that's why I asked here. `S = ...` and the line that generate the error are two separate lines of code. Both lines are quoted on my question. There isn't a `log10(S.^2)` anywhere... maybe my math is out of date, but taking a negative value to 2nd power makes it a positive value, right?

Comment: @Petersaber It's good that you ask, but you must provide enough information, and not just what _you_ think is relevant. By "enough" I mean that we need complete runnable code that reproduces the problem, including representative inputs. If you keep insisting on providing "observations" instead of code, this discussion will forever be based on guesses and unlikely to help future readers. I strongly urge you to consider following our advice in this respect. At the very least, please provide an answer to Ander's inquiry for both of your test cases.